# how to run sublime text javaScript file in my already installed terminus?

Tags: sublimetext3

I did succeed installing the terminal emulator (Terminus) in sublime text editor but I am bit confuse on how to even get started running my JavaScript files. I can only run JavaScript file in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is designed to run inside a javascript engine which is traditionally available inside of browsers. To run javascript on your local machine from a terminal you need an engine to do so. You should look into node.js which is designed for doing exactly this.